Azure DevOps and Power Automate Work Item Update
I create a flow that send a mail once a user story is created at Azure DevOps but it is triggerd with any item update and I want to trigger just when the user Story change between Board Columns
Not sure how to define at the trigger to just see updates in one field

@Expiscornovus I saw you have answer a similar question but tried it and it didnt work


Not sure how to define at the trigger to just see updates in one field

It's not supported in Power automate to monitor if the field is changed. There are existing feature request in community, please check link here and here.
The sample condition is checking the field value(equal,greater...etc) than a specific value.
There is no such new vaule like expression @greater(length(string(item()?['fields']?['System.BoardColumn']?['newValue'])), 0), only triggerOutputs()?['body/fields/System_BoardColumn'] is available.
As a workaround, you can monitor the field change in DevOps webhook， send HTTP request to power automate, use HTTP request is received trigger in power automate.

Generate the HTTP url from Power Automate HTTP request is received trigger, copy and paste to devops webhook above.

When i change the work item board column, it will trigger the power automate.

You can get the dynamic content from triggeroutput. For example:
The oldValue of field System.BoardColumn: triggerOutputs()?['body/resource/fields/System.BoardColumn/oldValue'] 
The newValue of field System.BoardColumn: triggerOutputs()?['body/resource/fields/System.BoardColumn/newValue'] 


Thanks! was really helpful, and how could I change the body of the HTTP into segments to use the information a dynamic contect? for the mail for example

You can parse the triggerOutputs to get the field value, i added the content in the reply, thanks.

unfortunately the connector is a non compliance node for me, is there another solution?

@VictorManuelCortez, you can search the mail as keyword and try other email actions from power automate. If non compliance also reported for other mail actions, you need to contact your company IT admin. The point here is to get the field value from the trigger output. If you still have queries on the email action, you can raise a new ticket with mail action detail error to get further help :)

@VictorManuelCortez, may i know how is it going? Let me know if there's any further query on the ticket. The trigger and field syntax is working on my side.
